# What is the best plot I can do to understand true values vs errors in prediction in a regression problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, data-visualization, boxplot

I am facing a regression problem and I would like to understand how my errors distrubuite along the true values I have. For the moment, I have done this scatterplot:

[image]

but I want a plot that directly gives me how the error is strong for every true values. A solution could be dividing true values in bins and, for each one, computing a box-plot of the error. Finally, obtaining a plot like this

[image]

I wonder if there is a nicer plot and a better way to show that. Maybe something very easy to implement already exist in seaborn but at the moment nothing comes to my mind.

Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Errors will always relate to Y, e.g., low Y will be overpredicted unless $R^2$=1.  So errors are plotted against X or functions of X such as predicted Y.

Binning of continuous variables is always arbitrary and information-losing.

Your plot displays a possible fundamental error in the model formulation: an unmodeled nonlinearity.